# I can't select mailboxes in geary 0.11.3. Only the first inbox is active

Tags: xubuntu, configuration, email, geary

I installed geary 0.11.3 in my xubuntu then I added two accounts (first yahoo, second gmail), the messages where syncronized, BUT I only can see and select the first mailbox of the account that I added. I can see all mailboxes for all accounts (yahoo,gmail) but I can't select anyone!!!! only the inbox of Yahoo is active [image]displaying the messages, is this a bug? or I need to reinstall geary? thanks, Vladimir. I attach a screenshot of my geary showing that.

Comment: Same here in my elementary OS freya.
i opened a report too. here:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/cannot-select-folders-mailboxes-geary-0-11-3

Answer (score 0):

Does making the folder list a bit wider (by dragging the spacer between it and the conversation list) help at all?

Comment: It doesn't help at all ! I have only the first inbox active and I can't select the others mailboxes, this is annoying! I remove geary and then reinstall again but it didn't help.

Comment: Okay, well that's definitely a bug. Can you provide a debug log by running the command "geary -d |& tee geary.out" in a terminal window, try to click some folders then quit geary. Attach the file geary.out either here or perferably on this bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776981 so I can look into it? Thanks!

Comment: ok I attach my geary.out to have a look.

Comment: ok I attach my geary.out to have a look. (https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23780463/)

Comment: I have installed geary version 0.11.3 and I couldn't select any mailboxes then I downgraded to version 0.10.0 to see what happen, but the bug is the some, the debug file is for version 0.10.0 , I posted that at bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here (ubuntu 16.04 LTS). I just got a mail in one of the "unreachable" mailboxes. When selecting the mailbox from the drop-down menu (top-right) I can enter the inbox. Sadly you can't select the inbox if you haven't got new mails.

A solution could be to mail yourself if you really need to enter the inbox until geary comes with an update.